# Choosing random lines from file takes too long in BASH

Tags: performance, algorithm, bash, random

So I have this script which has this syntax:

```
./script number file
```

Where **number** the the number of lines I want to get from file **file**. These lines are chosen random and then two times printed. Considering a very big file ~ 1 000 000 lines, this algorithm **runs just too slow**. I don't know why because the printing just consists of accessing arrays.

```
#!/bin/bash

max=`wc -l $2 | cut -d " " -f1`

users=(`shuf -i 0-$max -n $1`)
pages=(`shuf -i 0-$max -n $1`)

readarray lines < $2

for (( i = 0; i < $1; i++ )); do
    echo L ${lines[${users[i]}]} ${lines[${pages[i]}]} 
done

for (( i = 0; i < $1; i++ )); do
    echo U ${lines[${users[i]}]} ${lines[${pages[i]}]} 
done
```

Comment: Arrays are notoriously inefficient in Bash, you should be able to do this with a for loop for number then using the $RANDOM Bash variable modded to get line numbers in bounds, then you can build a string and print with sed like, sed -n '4p;500p;245p;6773334p;34322p'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do without arrays at all, just using file utilities and temporary files:

```
# Put the shuf outputs in two separate files:

shuf -n "$1" "$2" > shuf_users
shuf -n "$1" "$2" > shuf_pages

# paste the two:
paste -d ' ' shuf_users shuf_pages | sed 's/^/L /'
paste -d ' ' shuf_pages shuf_users | sed 's/^/U /'
```

In @rici's solution, the culprit might also be in the two loops that output the lines (such `for` loops are notoriously slow).

You should use `mktemp` to create the temp files `shuf_users` and `shuf_pages`. This exercise is left to the reader.

Comment: @Horkyze be careful, I swapped `shuf_users` and `shuf_pages` in the second `paste` statement.

Comment: @Horkyze: Have a look at @rici's solution in his Note 2, it's pretty good! I guess I would've proceeded like that if I hadn't misread your question `:)`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `shuf` to select the lines, which is what it was designed for. For example (see note):

```
readarray users < <(shuf -n $1 "$2")
readarray pages < <(shuf -n $1 "$2")
for (( i = 0; i < $1; i++ )); do
    echo L ${users[i]} ${pages[i]} 
done
for (( i = 0; i < $1; i++ )); do
    echo U ${users[i]} ${pages[i]} 
done
```

This will still be slow, because `shuf` needs to read the entire file in order to find the line-endings, and you're invoking it twice, but it may well be faster than reading the entire file into memory as a bash array, particularly if you don't have a lot of memory available. (It also won't work if the second argument to the script is not a regular file; if it is a pipe, you can't read it twice.)

You could speed it up by selecting both sets of lines at once and then dividing them between `users` and `pages` but you'd need to do some work to get an unbiased distribution, assuming that you care about that.

---

**Note 1:**

As noted by @gniourf_gniourf in a comment, you would get a more accurate rendering of the lines by using the `-t` option to `readarray` and then quoting the arguments to `echo`. Also, `mapfile` is the preferred name for `readarray`:

```
mapfile -t users < <(shuf -n $1 "$2")
mapfile -t pages < <(shuf -n $1 "$2")
for (( i = 0; i < $1; i++ )); do
    echo L "${users[i]}" "${pages[i]}" 
done
for (( i = 0; i < $1; i++ )); do
    echo U "${users[i]}" "${pages[i]}"
done
```

**Note 2:**

You are probably better off not using arrays if `$1` is large. Here is one possible solution:

```
lines="$(paste -d' ' <(shuf -n $1 "$2") <(shuf -n $1 "$"))"
sed 's/^/L /' <<<"$lines"
sed 's/^/U /' <<<"$lines"
```

Comment: Is there a speed difference between `readarray users < <(shuf -n $1 lines)` and `readarray users <<< "$(shuf -n $1 lines)"` ?

Comment: @EdouardThiel: The first one will be faster if `$1` is large, because the second one requires an intermediate step of creating a string in memory and then creating a pipe to read the string from memory. (At least, I think it will be faster; I didn't actually benchmark it.)

Comment: @rici You're probably right but it is worth to be checked. Horkyze could you check on your data and tell what is the fastest method?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: OK, added the suggestion. It's orthogonal to the question, IMHO.

Comment: I have checked on a text file having 150,000,000 lines; the `<<<` solution is two times faster than the `< <(` one. Surprising!

Comment: No selection; just running `time readarray -t arr1 < <(cat file.txt)` gives 48s, and `time readarray -t arr1 <<< "$(cat file.txt)"` gives 24s.

Comment: `<<<` is also fater for me, just few seconds tho. `< <(` had 3m23.066s and `<<<` had 2m55.413s Command was in both cases: ./generate 100000 pages

Comment: Tx, so `<<<` wins in this case.

Comment: Yes, however ~3 mins is still to long for 100,000 lines. I will maybe consider doing this in C. Anyway thanks for the help. @rici answer accepted.

Comment: @EdouardThiel: I'll bet that the difference comes from the caching of file reads. Did you just run the trial once? Which one did you do first?

Comment: @Horkyze: Yes, for 100,000 lines, indexing `bash` arrays will be too slow.

Comment: @rici I run it several times.

Comment: @EdouardThiel: Interesting.

Comment: @rici I have checked `time cat file.txt | readarray -t arr1` just to see (it is useless since `readarray` lives in a subshell), it takes 48s too.

Comment: @EdouardThiel: yeah, that seems to be an issue with `readarray`. When it's input is a pipe, it falls back to a carefully synchronized character-at-a-time read so that when it hits a newline it hasn't read too far, in case the next command will read from the same pipe, and you've set a line limit in the readarray command. That doesn't apply to the `<<<` case because that just slurps the entire input into a temporary file (there's no option to slurp less than the whole file).

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you want fairly quickly, bash arrays are slow and built with temp files so you performance should be no better using them - they would be a decent feature if they were implemented by the Bash maintainers properly but they are not quite there yet:

`File (make sure to name it the same, this is recursive):` **ranlines.bsh**

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i max=$(wc -l $2 | cut -d " " -f1)+1
declare STR=""
declare -i random_line=0
declare tmp_file="/tmp/_$$_$(date)"
declare -r usr_file="/tmp/_user_3434"
declare -r pgs_file="/tmp/_pgs_4343"

## create our tmp_file and tell it dont use 0 
echo "0" >> "$tmp_file" 

for (( i = 0; i < $1; i++ )); do
 while :; do 
   random_line=$(($RANDOM*30%$max));
   ## if you find an entry already in the tmp_file then continue 
   ## get a new number, loop until you find a new number
   (($(grep -c "$random_line" "$tmp_file"))) && continue;
   echo "$random_line" >> "$tmp_file" 
   break; 
 done 
 ## build the sed print string
 STR="$STR${random_line}p;"
done
rm "$tmp_file" 

if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then 
 #usr_file
 eval "sed -n '$STR' $2" > "$usr_file" 
 ## call us again, this time for the U 
 ranlines.bsh $1 $2 "U"
else 
 ## we know already we are processing the U because args is not 2 
 declare -i random_slct=$1+1
 eval "sed -n '$STR' $2" > "$pgs_file" 
 paste <(sed -n "${random_slct}q; a L" "$2") "$usr_file" "$pgs_file"
 paste <(sed -n "${random_slct}q; a U" "$2") "$pgs_file" "$usr_file"
 rm "$pgs_file" "$usr_file"
fi   
exit 0
```